# Save hibernate.cfg.xml after changes

Tags: java, hibernate, properties, configuration

I want to save my hibernate.cfg.xml after some property changes.I can change properties at run time but I need to save changes, so I can access new properties at next executions.

In hibernate.cfg.xml I have properties like:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
      //...
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username">berkan</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123456</property>
      //...
   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I can change properties with setProperty() at run time like:

```
configuration = new Configuration().configure();
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "berkantest");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "098765");
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build());
```

But after stop currently executed build I cant access new username and password at next executions.I want to save them in hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

The direction in which you are thinking is very wrong.  Usually it is the system user(dedicated user for the component or subsystem) that is placed in the hibernate configuration file. If you intend to have a dedicated connection per user this implies your database server already has all these users and passwords created one way or another. I would suggest to not save the user at all, or if you would like to save the user save it outside the hibernate config file under some table or file with name - LastLoggedUser for example.

Usualy a multiuser scenario is coded in following way. You have one or more database users that may have different permissions f.ex. - read only user for reporting and read write user for regular usage. Then on top you model your logical users. You cab have f.ex. a table in the database named user where teh regular users will use the database user for read,write and the users doing analytics will have access to the reporting user. Now this is only an example.

Just don't try to modify your hibernate config file in runtime. 9/10 case this is wrong.